# delete replied message pycord

Tags: python, discord, pycord

how can I make my bot delete the message I've replied in discord.py?
I have only code for standard clear command

```
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
@bot.slash_command(description="Clears X messages.")
@discord.option("num", description="amount of messages")
@discord.option("target", description="from specific member")
async def clear(ctx, num: int, target: discord.Member=None):
    if num > 500 or num < 0:
        return await ctx.send("Invalid amount. Maximum is 500.")
    def msgcheck(amsg):
        if target:
           return amsg.author.id == target.id
        return True
    deleted = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=num, check=msgcheck)
    EmbClear = discord.Embed(title=":white_check_mark:Success!", description=f':thumbsup: Deleted **{len(deleted)}/{num}** messages.')
    await ctx.respond(embed=EmbClear, delete_after=5)
```

Comment: That's not discord.py. Which fork do you use?

Comment: I use pycord lib

Comment: Then, please replace discord.py tag with the pycord tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to delete a message, you will need the `Manage Messages` permission. You can add this permission to your bot by opening your server's settings, going to the "permissions" tab and selecting `Manage Messages` from the available options.
Once you've done that, you can delete a message with the following command: `message.delete()`

You can use the `delete()` function on the Message object that you get back from replying. For example:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = await message.channel.send('Hello!')
        await msg.delete()
```